# Installing ros-melodic-desktop uninstalls python3-catkin-pkg

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See relevant GitHub tracking ticket with more info and steps [here](https://github.com/ros-tooling/aws-oncall/issues/69).

I am attempting to build a ROS2 package that uses ROS1 bridge ([rosbag2_bag_v2](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2_bag_v2)) in a GitHub Actions CI pipeline. I am able to install the dependencies for ROS1 which include `python3-catkin-pkg`. However, when I run `apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop`, it automatically removes `python3-catkin-pkg`:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
python3-catkin-pkg python3-rosdep python3-rosdep-modules python3-rosdistro
python3-rospkg
```

Is there a reason this occurs and is it possible to install a ROS1 distro without removing `python3-catkin-pkg`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345875/installing-ros-melodic-desktop-uninstalls-python3-catkin-pkg/) by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a reason this occurs

ROS1 / `catkin_make` uses `python-catkin-pkg` to parse `package.xml`.
In ROS2 / `colcon` `python3-catkin-pkg` is used.

These 2 [packages conflict](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/blob/2977726b32f57205ac0985ce9eb8f44e5dbbe8bf/stdeb.cfg#L10-L11) as they install the same scripts.
The libraries can be installed side by side since some modules packages have been created:
`python3-catkin-pkg-modules` and `python-catkin-pkg`: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/157

> is it possible to install a ROS1 distro without removing python3-catkin-pkg

Not that I know of, as these packages conflict.
On the bright side I'd expect most of these packages to be reinstalled in their python2 variant along with ROS1.
You'll just end up with the python2 version of the executables instead of the python3 one.
If I were you I would just run that install and then reinstall the uninstalled modules like `python3-rosdep-modules`

A better long term resolution would be for packages that use the python modules but not the scripts to declare their dependencies on `python(3)-pkg-name-modules` instead of `python(3)-pkg-name`.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on 2020-03-06**:
Thank you for the explanation